# How many calendar days elapsed since given date?

Tags: python

I need to find how many calendar days elapsed sice given date. When I use the following, it gives me -1 even when the date is today:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> t = datetime.fromisoformat('2023-03-09 08:55:11')
>>> (t - datetime.today()).days
-1
```

Whereas the correct answer should be 0.

If I ask at `00:00:01`, and the date was yesterday at `23:59:59`, it should give me 1 day. But anything today should be 0.

How can I do that?

Comment: [_"Note that normalization of negative values may be surprising at first."_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) `days` will always be negative for negative deltas, so that the `seconds` and `microseconds` can be positive.

Comment: `(datetime.today() - t).days`?

Comment: Convert both values to dates instead of datetimes. It's like comparing `0.9` to `1.1` and wanting the result to be `1`, converting them both to integers first would give `0` and `1` with a difference of `1`. So, compare dates, not datetimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert both values to dates instead of datetimes.

It's like comparing 0.9 to 1.1 and wanting the result to be 1. Converting them both to integers first would give 0 and 1 with a difference of 1.

So, compare dates, not datetimes...

```
from datetime import datetime, date

x = datetime.fromisoformat('2023-03-09 08:55:11')
y = datetime.fromisoformat('2023-03-10 07:00:00')

print((y - x).days)
print((y.date() - x.date()).days)
print()

y = datetime.fromisoformat('2023-03-10 09:00:00')
print((y - x).days)
print((y.date() - x.date()).days)
```

Demo : https://trinket.io/python3/013ac6c02a

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, date

given_date = datetime.fromisoformat('2023-03-09 08:55:11')
today = datetime.now().date() # get current date without time
elapsed_days = (today - given_date.date()).days

print(elapsed_days)
```

Answer (score -3):

The reason you are getting a negative result is that you are subtracting the current date from a future date. You can use math.abs, or just:

```
t= datetime.fromisoformat('2023-03-01')
elapsed_days = (datetime.today() - t).days
print(elapsed_days)
```